# Existence of a function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, dg.differential-geometry

[also asked here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307197]

All arguments are in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Suppose $n(x)$ is a smooth function where $\mathbf{supp}(n(x)-1)$ is a compact set $\Omega$. i.e. $n(x) = 1$ when $x$ is outside $\Omega$.

Assume there are some points $x_j\in\Omega$, where $j=1,2,\cdots.m$.

Consider Helmholtz equation

$\Delta u + k^2 n(x) u = 0$

And I want to know if there is a function $u$ satisfies the equation and also vanishes at $x_j$. i.e. $u(x_j) = 0$. [Certainly $u$ can have a manifold of zeros, here I just restrict it on $x_j$]

Here you may try to give a method to construct $u$, or prove the existence.

And you may take $m=1$ here at first.

Thanks.

Comment: This was crossposted to math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307197 . In the future, please wait some time before posting your question in multiple fora, and when you do, provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to see hear from you that you'd already gotten the solution elsewhere.

Comment: ok, I will put the link here.

Answer (score 1):

I proved the existence [here](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/yzhong/seminar/IP_Point_Source.pdf).